# How many different equivalent relations can you define on set of three elements?

Tags: equivalence-relations

Let X be a set of three elements ${a,b,c}$.

1.How many different relations can you define?

> The answer is 9, as $R\subset X \times X$

This is easy to see for me, I imagine it as  a ~ a, a ~ b, ..., c ~ a, ...

2.How many different equivalent relations can you define?

> The answer is five. The argument is that you can list all partitions: {{a},{b},{c}},{{a,b},{c}},{{a},{b,c}},{{a,c},{b}},{{a,b,c}}.

What I'm not following is that to have an equivalence relation I must show that it's reflexive (i.e. a ~ a), symmetric (i.e. a ~ b = b ~ a) and transitive (i.e. a ~ b, b ~ c = a ~ c). Which for me covers one equivalence relation; involving three elements. How do the rest four look like?!

Comment: I'm not sure you understand what an equivalence relation is. Consider the partition $\{\{a,b\},\{c\}\}$ of $\{a,b,c\}$. The corresponding equivalence relation is the following table:$$\begin{array}{c|c}\text{Relation}&\text{T/F}\\\hline a\sim a&T\\a\sim b&T\\a\sim c&F\\b\sim a&T\\b\sim b&T\\b\sim c&F\\c\sim a&F\\c\sim b&F\\c\sim c&T\end{array}$$Can you see why this relation is an equivalence relation?Likewise, for the partition $\{\{a\},\{b\},\{c\}\}$, the corresponding equivalence relation is

Comment: $$\begin{array}{c|c}\text{Relation}&\text{T/F}\\\hline a\sim a&T\\a\sim b&F\\a\sim c&F\\b\sim a&F\\b\sim b&T\\b\sim c&F\\c\sim a&F\\c\sim b&F\\c\sim c&T\end{array}$$ Can you see why this is a different equivalence relation?

Comment: I see ... but ... take the same partition $\{\{a\},\{b\},\{c\}\}$. I do see relations, but I do not see that any of them are symmetric or transitive. Hence what I do not understand that makes  this partition $\{\{a\},\{b\},\{c\}\}$ an equivalence relation.

Comment: What part of the second table I wrote isn't symmetric or transitive? Show me a violation of either condition.

Comment: oh .. I think I see it now! The relations just does not need to be true; a ~ b = F = b ~a. It just has to be consistent.

Comment: No, it's that if there is an $a$ and $b$ such that $a\sim b$, then $b\sim a$. In this relation, that's only the case when $a=b$, but that is trivial.

Comment: ok, so take partition $\{\{a,b\},\{c\}\}$ - then a ~ b and b ~ a if $a=a$, $b=b$ or $a=b$. But in another partition $\{\{a\},\{b\},\{c\}\}$ - a ~ b and b ~ a iff $a=b$

Comment: likewise, if I take partition $\{\{a,c\},\{b\}\}$ - then transitive property is possible if $a=a$, $b=b$ or $c=c$. But in another partition $\{a,b,c\}$ - transitive property is possible when a, b and c are distinct. I hope i'm right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer for part (1) is incorrect. Any relation on a set $X$ is a subset of $X \times X$. Thus the number of relations is the size of the power set of $X \times X$. In this particular case, $|X \times X|=9$, thus the power set will have size $2^9=512$ relations.

For part (2): Partitions of a set are in one-one correspondence with the equivalence relations on the set, i.e. for each partition, there is an equivalence relation and vice versa.

For example, if we have the partition $\{\{a,b\}, \{c\}\}$, then the elements living in one "part" of the partition will be equivalent to each other. Thus the relation corresponding to this partition will be
$$R=\{(a,a), (a,b), (b,a), (b,b), (c,c)\}.$$

Likewise, the relation for the partition $\{\{a\},\{b\}, \{c\}\}$, the corresponding relation will be 
$$S=\{(a,a), (b,b), (c,c)\}.$$

Comment: You appear to be completely misunderstanding.  First a set does not "have" reflexive or symmetric relations, it **satisfies** those rules.  Further, those rules start *IF*!  "If (x, y) is in the set, so is (y, x)".  "If (x, y) and (y, z) are in the set so is (x, z)".  For set S there are NO "(a, b)" or "(a, c)", or "(b, c)" so those never arise.

Comment: It's not so bad. The concept is slowly crystallising.

Answer (score 0):

A relation on $X$ is any member of the power set of $X \times X$.

Thus an example if $X = \{a,b,c\} $ is $R_1 = \{ a\sim b, c\sim c \}$ but of course this is not an equivalence relation (for example, we would not have $R_1 (a,a)$ which is $a\sim a$).

So there are $2^9$ relations on a three-element set.  The answer of $9$ is wrong.

An equivalence relation must include $\bigcup_{x\in x} x\sim x$ so in our case it must include each of $a\sim a$,  $b\sim b$,  $c\sim c$.  And it must satisfy 
$$\forall{x,y \in X} : (x \sim y \in R) \implies (y \sim x \in R)$$
 And it must also satisfy 
$$\forall{x,y,z \in X} : (x \sim y \in R) \wedge (y \sim z \in R)\implies (x \sim z \in R)$$
So our equivalence relation $E$ can be formed in exactly 5 ways:

(1) All relations in $E$ are of the form $x = x$.

(2) $E$ includes all relations of the form $x=y$ for any pair $(x,y)$.  (This can be expressed by the shorthand $ a \sim b \sim c$.

(3) - (5) The union of case (1) with the two relationships $x \sim y, y \sim x $ for some particular pair of distinct elements $(x,y)$.  For example, $\{ a \sim a, b\sim b, c\sim c, a\sim b, b\sim a\}$.  Since there are three ways to select the "odd man out" among the three elements, 3 such relationships exist.

Answer (score 0):

Partitions of a set are in one-one correspondence with the equivalence relations on the set, i.e. for each partition, there is an equivalence relation and vice versa.

For the set with the three elements $\{a,b,c\}$ there are five ways to partition them while the classes of each partition are disjoint and the union of the classes in each partition equals the set (by definition of a partition}.

First possible partition: $\{\{a\},\{b\},\{c\}\} : 3$ classes, each class with $1$ element.

$2$nd possible partition: $\{\{a,b\},\{c\}\} 2$ classes, one with elements $a,b$ and the other with $c$.

Similarly we see three other possible partitions:  $\{\{a\},\{b,c\}\},\{\{a,c\},\{b\}\}$, and $\{\{a,b,c\}\}$.

Because these are the only five possible ways we can partition the set into disjoint classes, whose union equals exactly the original set $\{a,b,c\}$ , we conclude that there are five equivalent relations.

That is of the $512$ possible relations on the set $\{a,b,c\}$ only five are equivalent relations. Verify that each relation corresponding to each partition is an equivalent relation.