# The equivalence relation is defined on a set of 9 elements and is negatively transitive relation. How many equivalence classes can be there?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations, equivalence-relations

I looked for answers a lot but mostly used the Bell number, which we haven't studied. And I have no idea how to do it with negatively transitive relations..

(Edit) Negatively transitive relation, according to our lecturer:

R is negatively transitive if and only if:

∀x,y,z∈S:¬(xRy)∧¬(yRz)⟹¬(xRz)

By De Morgan's Laws, this can be given the alternative form:

∀x,y,z∈S:(xRz)⟹(xRy)∨(yRz)

(Also a note that we don't study this in English, so there might be some mistakes in the explanation, I'm sorry for this)

I tried to count all possible relations for 9 elements first, which was 2^18, and then tried to find the partitions of a set (the equivalence relations on the set). For 9 elements was hard, but for 3 elements it was:

First possible partition: {{a},{b},{c}}:3
classes, each class with 1
element.

2
nd possible partition: {{a,b},{c}}2
classes, one with elements a,b
and the other with c
.

Similarly we see three other possible partitions: {{a},{b,c}},{{a,c},{b}}
, and {{a,b,c}}
.

(Source: [How many different equivalent relations can you define on set of three elements?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3483142/how-many-different-equivalent-relations-can-you-define-on-set-of-three-elements))

And the answer was 5 equivalent relations.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to tell us what "negatively transitive" means, and what you have tried. Can you solve the problem for sets with fewer elements? (Don't respond in a comment.)

Comment: You seem to be counting how many equivalence relations you can have satisfying the given properties, but you also quoted the question as asking how many equivalence **classes** there are, which would be a question about a specific equivalence relation, something entirely different.

Comment: Oh, yes, it is. I was stuck after counting equivalence relations and couldn't continue from that on.. thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

You counted the equivalence relations (which correspond to partitions) but you never took into account the "negatively transitive" property.

For example, consider the equivalence relation corresponding to the partition $\{\{a,b\},\{c\}\}$. This is not "negatively transitive": because we have $aRb$, so therefore by the definition of negatively transitive, we must have either $aRc$ or $cRb$, but we have neither.

In fact, if $R$ is an equivalence relation that is also "negatively transitive", then it must be the total relation (everything is related to everything)!

Why?

Well, let $a$ and $b$ be any elements of the set. Because $R$ is reflexive, we know that $aRa$ holds. Since $R$ is negatively transitive, we have
$$aRa\implies aRb \vee bRa.$$
But because $R$ is symmetric, $bRa\implies aRb$ anyway. Therefore, we conclude that $aRb$ holds.

Since $a$ and $b$ were arbitrary elements, it follows that $R$ is the total relation.

That means that there is exactly one equivalence class.